# Warning use of old-style cast while casting OpenCV Mat image to QImage?

Tags: c++, image, qt, opencv, qimage

While I've been using OpenCV with QT, I've seen that warning which I have no idea what's its new cast style. Anybody knows so that I can apply?

```
    Mat normalImage;
    normalImage = imread("E:\\tree.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR );
    cvtColor(normalImage, normalImage, COLOR_BGR2RGB);
    QImage imdisplay((uchar*)normalImage.data, normalImage.cols, 
    normalImage.rows, normalImage.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
    ui->imageLabel1->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(imdisplay));
```

```
QImage imdisplay((uchar*)normalImage.data, normalImage.cols, 
normalImage.rows, normalImage.step, QImage::Format_RGB888);
```

That is the part of old-style casting

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast "old style cast" is a synonym for C-style cast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @VTT "old-style cast" means "C-style" cast.
C++ compilers prefer the use of C++ casts:

- static_cast
- dynamic_cast
- const_cast
- reinterpret_cast

In your case it is caused by `(uchar*)normalImage.data`.
But I am wondering if you need any cast at all since `Mat::data` is documented to be `uchar *`: https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat